# Azure SQL Database-level firewall rules

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

In my Azure account, I have a server with n databases. I want some different restrictions on the various databases, of which IPs are allowed to view the content. [This article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-firewall-configure/) says that you can set server-level and database-level firewalls to do what I want, however, in the portal it seems you are only able to set the server-level firewall, and not the database-level - this must be done using something like SQL Database Management Studio. And here comes my question..

I am by no means an expert on how IPs work, but is there not a chance that my IP will change, at some point? If the list of allowed IPs are saved inside the database, and at some point I lose this access, how will I be able to get back in??

Comment: hi there,
the rule and by that the trick is here to add then the ip to server level (by means of powershell or portal) temporary , then change the db ip and then remove the ip from server level again. The rules kick in like this: if allowed on server, then server will allow, if not in that range on server then db will check and allow / deny, elseway nothing happens. additionally you could set up a vnet with a P2S connection and make sure that SQL is accessible from Azure (rule 0.0.0.0)

Comment: Ohh, if this is how it works, it makes things a lot easier :P Ill test it in a bit!